# Firebase - securing Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

As I understand anyone can get the Data Url (https://to-do-list-it-is.firebaseio.com/) from my source code, build an application using this Url that will display all the data from this Url which can be happily manipulated. Or at least tracked.

Lets say I want to build a contact form using Firebase. Everyone can send contact details to Firebase App but only I can view the details and delete or edit data. What is the security on this? Does someone has an experience with this?

Comment: Common! Show you face you coward down-voter! If you are able to down vote I am sure you are able to answer the question right?

Comment: Had been answered already:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the security features of Firebase (this might be helpful: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/).
With this feature you can create a rule that matches your needs.