# Setting rules on Firebase Database on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've got `Firebase` Database working on iOS.

Everywhere the doc tells me that using

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}
```

Will make the DB open to "the world". So I want to limit access to my app only. The doc says how to append user auth and rules according til this.
But I just want general auth for the app, not per user.

How do I achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "general auth for the app"? What users are allowed to read/write the data and which users aren't?

Comment: Any user, using my specific app. How do I grant requests from the app, not per user? If someone tries to call my database from i.e. Postman, it should be illegal.

Comment: That's not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase