# Verify domain in client side JS in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, react-native

When using a web service like Google Maps, I expose the API key and set the domain on their server so it won’t be abused. When working with JS in iOS, like React Native, how do I replace the "domain" step.

Comment: The client API key and database URL are not secrets, they are meant to be shared with the users of your app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase

Comment: Right, I guess the Google Maps API is a more applicable example as the token used for the service is the auth.