# Restrict Firebase Database write access to a single app

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it somehow possible to restrict the write access of the realtime database to only my Android app and give my Website only read access.

As users can only view their data on the website, I don't want people to be able to create stuff in the database with their own Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to restrict access to a specific app or a specific piece of code, unless you turn (users of) that app into a specific "user" of the system. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase