# Restrict Firebase database access to one Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm working on an Android app that reads from a [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).  App users won't be logging in or modifying the database.  All app users will be looking at the same data; I'm using Firebase for its real-time update features.

Ideally, I would like to restrict access to the database so that only my app can read the data.

I am aware of a few things I could do:

**1. Write security rules that allows anyone to read**, that is

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": false
  }
}
```

Con: Anyone can read :(

**2. Write security rules that [allow authenticated users to read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data), then hard code the username and password into the app**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$user_id":{
       ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
       ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Con: Hard coding a username and password in an app seems very wrong.  Plus, it doesn't actually lock down the database, since anyone could decompile the app, grab the `google-services.json` and the hard-coded user name/password, and write their own app that shared my package name.

Googling has revealed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535093/restrict-firebase-database-write-access-to-a-single-app), which is specific to writing, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase), which says "no" but is a few years old.

What is the correct approach restricting access to the database?  Am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

Comment: The answer you linked is still correct: there is no way to limit access to your Firebase Database to just your app.

Comment: Okay, thank you @FrankvanPuffelen.

Comment: What's your final choice?

Comment: @michiyo did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: No, to my knowledge there is no way.

Answer (score 7):

**3. Use `FirebaseAuth` and `signInAnonymously()` method**

reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Then adjust security rules:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ...
      }
    }
```

Con: multiple accounts used only for reading the same data

Comment: This seems even less secure than #2, since I'd be giving up the ability hide/encrypt/obfuscate (not great, but better than nothing?) a username and password.  Can you clarify why you think this is better?

Answer (score -1):

When you add your application to Firebase project, you must specify SHA1 certificate of your app, so nobody is able to access your data except you.

Comment: It's not true. With `".read": true,` anyone can access web based database interface via http://project_name.firebaseio.com/