# Firebase Rules settings

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I decided to use Firebase in an old objectiv C iOS app.

I installed what I needed following the instructions given here:
`Add Firebase to your iOS app` right after login into Firebase.
Then I followed the instructions given here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/
in order to work with a database.

At this point it basically works, I can write some data.
Nevertheless I have this issue about the Rules settings.

I followed the information given here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

But if I set my rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

it works as expected. On the other hand, if I set them like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

which is the default and should allow me to write data from my app, it does not work.

What is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the user is not signed in.

Comment: OK. It sounds like I did not fully understand what I read. Actually reading again I can see that you are right. I would like my app (but only this app) to be able to access the DB for writing and reading, whoever the user is, but I would also like to do this without requesting the user to login. Is this possible?

Comment: Access is granted to users, not to a specific app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user to login, you could automatically authenticate the user anonymously.

[Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)

Then you could use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment in reply to `cartant`,it is clear that you want to allow your app users to access your `database` for reading and writing , without need of signing in.

***I would also like to do this without requesting the user to login. Is this possible?***

**YES**

It is possible to allow your users to access your DB without any signing process.

Actually

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

this rule says that you are providing `read` and `write` permission to your user without signing in.

On the other hand

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

in this rule you are mentioning that your authentication `("auth != null")`has to be performed before granting the `read` , `write` permissions to your user.

**So to accomplish your goal just use the default rule i.e rule without authentication.**

Comment: Indeed, and as mentioned in the starting post I already have this working. But in this case I am giving full access to the whole word. That is a bit too much. Just one note: THIS IS NOT the default rule.