# Database rule in Firebase: Can we setting each rule for each application in the same project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My project has 2 application. One application just run in a specific mobile device which we known, it interact with firebase without authenication. The another is run in many mobile devices, it must sign-in into firebase to communicate each other.

So my question is how I can configure in Database rule in Firebase, what wildcards I need to use to specify appID like UID?

Comment: You cannot secure database access to allow a specific app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase

Comment: Don't repost your question please. It wastes everyone's time. If you have more information on your original question, use the edit link under that question to provide the additional information.