# Semi-authenticated access to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'd like to use a firebase to store data from a web application, which is entirely static-hosted (i.e. all the code is client side). I don't really want the users to have to authenticate - it's basic data capture, nothing personal, and no need for them to have accounts. But I would like to take whatever steps are possible to protect what would otherwise be a 'public' firebase.

So I had this thought. Is it possible in any way to restrict write access to firebase based on *where* the client code was served from? I.e., is there some way to allow client code that I serve from a specific domain to 'prove' to firebase that it really came from my domain?

Obviously a token of some kind isn't *that* helpful, since anyone could browse my server, grab the token, and then reuse it in their own code. But the only difference is that their own code wouldn't have originated on *my* server.

I suppose I'm wondering if, when a JS client makes a request to firebase, there is any way to know with reasonably certainty *where* that client code came from. I guess it might be something like CORS, but I'm not sure if that's a good analogy. And since my site is entirely static, I can't use the server-side API and authenticate that way.

This doesn't have to be 100% bullet-proof. Just making it tedious or tricky for someone to 'spoof' would be enough.

Comment: There is no way to restrict access to Firebase features based on the domain or app that runs the code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase

Comment: Tx - I did search, but that one didn't show up :( I thought as much. I'm now wondering if using firebase hosting as the static site offers extra possibilities for this. Will experiment.

Comment: OK. Good to hear that you were looking for that answer. Searching is indeed a bit hit or miss. I have better luck, since I often know what answer I'm looking for.