# Firebase Auth Database permissions by domain

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'd like to setup the rules for my Firebase database such that each authenticated user gets read access to a domain-specific node at: /domains/yourdomain.com

How do I change the following rule to allow for that?  As the 'matches' and 'endswith' operator expect literal values, and don't expand the $domain variable.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "domains": {
      "$domain": {
        ".read": "$auth.token.email.matches(/.*@$domain$/)",
        ".read": "$auth.token.email.endswitch($domain)",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase please read this answer

Comment: Or maybe you're actually looking for my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain

Comment: The first link only mentions authenticated users, but I need domain-specific authentication.  The second question is what I need, but the accepted answer forces the creation of a node like "gmailUsers" for each domain.  I don't want to have to create a separate rule for each domain.